# Diretório temporário sem valor no upload de imagens

Tags: php, xampp, image

Olá, na minha aplicação tenho um upload de imagens múltiplas, com quase todas as imagens funciona perfeitamente, porém em 1 imagem tive um problema e provavelmente deve acontecer mais vezes no futuro, então é melhor tentar resolver agora.

O problema é que ao fazer o upload dessa imagem ela cadastra no banco de dados normalmente, mas não move para a pasta de uploads como todas as outras, debugando o código descobri que o arquivo temporário dela não existe, então o código tenta busca-la para mover, mas não encontra, então não faz nada.

Estou usando o Xampp, a pasta temporária do xampp é: C:\xampp\tmp\arquivo.tmp

**Código:**

```
        // Get Images Informations

        $image_name = $_FILES['galeria']['name'];
        $image_dir = $_FILES['galeria']['tmp_name'];

        // Upload Directory
        $upload_dir = '../../../_main/uploads/';

        // Start Count
        $i = 0;

        while($i <= count($_FILES['galeria']['name'])) {
            // Allowed Extensions

            $extensions = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg');

            // Get Image Extension

            $img_ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image_name[$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            if(!in_array($img_ext, $extensions)) {
                header('Location: /new_product');
                $_SESSION['erro'] = 'img_ext';
                exit();
            }else {
                // New Image Name

                $new_image_name = mt_rand(1000, 1000000).'.'.$img_ext;

                // Move Image to Folder

                move_uploaded_file($image_dir[$i], $upload_dir.$product_id.'/'.$new_image_name);

                // Insert into DB

                $insert_step_2 = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO imagens_produtos (nome, id_produto) VALUES (:nome, :id_produto)');
                $insert_step_2->execute(array(
                    ':nome' => $new_image_name,
                    ':id_produto' => $product_id
                ));
            }

            $i++;

            if($i >= count($_FILES['galeria']['name'])) {

                // Return do New Product Page
                //header('Location: /new_product');
            }
        }
```

**Saída do var_dump**

```
array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "okokoko.jpg" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(1) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } }
```

**Imagem que está ocorrendo o erro:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEEGE.jpg

Comment: Faça `var_dump($_FILES); exit;` no PHP, envie a imagem que está dando o problema e adicione na pergunta a saída gerada na tela.

Comment: Fiz a adição das informações

Comment: Acabei de perceber o type vazio...